# persistence.xml for ejb deployed in glassfish

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish, glassfish-3, persistence.xml

folks,

i am trying to deploy a ear with a ejb in the ear root. the ejb has a persistence.xml file where the  tag has to be a jar file in the Glassfish's domain lib.  (this i have put it there because the jar is used across ears)

so what exactly should be the content of the  `<jar-file>*****/myjar.jar</jar-file>` tag, for the jar in the glassfish's domain lib directory.

thanks fr yure time,

rajan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path should be either an absolute path to a JAR (not recommended) or the simple file name for a JAR inside the EAR deployment file. So, assuming you have an EAR with the jars "ejbs.jar", "jpa.jar" and "myjar.jar", the `<jar-file>` tag in jpa.jar for myjar.jar should be:

```
<jar-file>myjar.jar</jar-file>
```

Comment: thanks fr yure reply, yes thats the problem exactly... my jar is outside the ear deployment... i have put in it in the glassfish domains lib directory...

Comment: Not sure it's correct nor supported to leave your jars there. I mean, your dependencies are supposed to be in the EAR, as the EAR should be a "deployable" artifact for your application, no matter which Application Server you are using. So, I would stick with the standards and benefit from its features, like using an "external" jar file via <jar-file> in the JPA jar :-)